# Trying to add gigya script through ISML but throwing errors

Tags: javascript

Trying to inject the gigya script in isml but its throwing errors
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfdD8.jpg)

I have tried possible things like calling that script using isprint and etc...
Also, tried injecting that file in from other path. but still no luck
I check if other scripts are interfering but no

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.